# Obtaining travel vaccinations without insurance in Austria

Tags: europe, health, austria

I plan on travelling to Kenya soon to do some volunteer work. As I have been travelling around for a long time I have given up my previous residency in the Netherlands which means I no longer have the national health insurance and my travel insurance has also run out.

So my question is; **is it possible for me to obtain vaccinations in Austria if I do not have any insurance?**

Can I just pay it out of my own pocket? Or is insurance required to even go see a doctor or specialist. I need to get the yellow fever vaccination.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the [Tropeninstitut](http://www.tropeninstitut.at/preise.htm) in Wien don't require that you have insurance. At any rate, it might be worth your while to contact them and ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Austria, the costs for travel vaccinations are not covered by the regular health insurance, but must be paid in full by the person requesting them. Source: [Austrian Government's Health Portal](https://www.gesundheit.gv.at/leben/gesundheitsvorsorge/impfungen/reiseimpfungen)

Not being insured should not prevent you from getting the recommended vaccinations.